# Is there a Bootstrap class to create a color under my image on hover like in my example?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWXYT.png As you can see here, there is a green underground effect on hover where it shifts slightly to the bottom right, making the image look like it's elevated.Is there a way to accomplish this with normal CSS or Bootstrap?

I already tried using borders and background colors but i can't get it right.

Comment: use box-shadow for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you're looking for is `box-shadow`

Use it like this:

```
img {
    webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

You may adjust the shadow and color in here [CSS Box Shadow](https://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)